# Square wave inverters for running water immersion heater elements

Tags: inverter, square

I am lead to believe that cheap square wave 230V inverters are generally considered not much use as they can damage sensitive equipment.

Do kettle elements count as sensitive equipment?

I would like to install an inverter that solely runs an immersion heater from a 48V folk lift truck battery.

Do I need a good inverter or is a square wave sufficient for running solely water heat elements?

Answer (score 2):

Square wave will be completely fine for an immersion heater. The heaters don't care much what you feed them - square, sine, whatever - it's just converted to heat.

> generally considered not much use as they can damage sensitive equipment

I kinda wonder what is considered "sensitive" these days, as most everything has a mains rectifier and uses a switchmode power supply. Those supplies will run from DC, square wave, sine wave, etc. - they just don't care as there is a dumb rectifier on the input.

The only "sensitive" devices I can imagine would be those that have actual mains frequency transformers, and mains-powered motors, and those can suffer from high core losses when driven from a square wave.

In practical terms, any modern electronic device that would get damaged from a square mains input waveform is IMHO inadequately designed. My electronics lab is full of sensitive equipment and it can all run from a square wave just fine - even devices with mains transformers in them. I've actually tried it a few years ago. A few measurement instruments show noisier results, but that's just a functional impairment rather than damage.

Comment: thanks, possibly "sensitive" was not the correct word i used there, i agree completely, i guess i just wanted to here someone else say it, most stuff you read tries to steer you away from square wave inverters, but it is generally just motors (or magnetic loads) that may suffer right? anything with a bridge rectifier or a none inductive load should be fine.

Comment: Modified sine wave ("square wave") inverters usually have fast rise and fall time waveforms that could cause high current transients through input diodes into bulk storage capacitors, and that might cause damage to these components. But there should be no problem with simple heaters (unless they use something like a phase modulated triac for temperature control).